# How to automatically share posts to facebook on iOS like Twitter

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, facebook-graph-api, twitter

I'd like to share posts to facebook using Facebook iOS SDK. I want to the system like twitter, if it is set the facebook share function on, Twitter automatically share the tweet to facebook.

I've implemented as following, however it always ask users. I wanna make it post automatically. If you have any advice, please tell me. Thank you for your kindness.

```
    var content: FBSDKShareLinkContent = FBSDKShareLinkContent()
    content.contentURL = NSURL(string:"https://~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
    var shareButton: FBSDKShareButton = FBSDKShareButton()
    shareButton.shareContent = content
    shareButton.center = self.view.center
    self.view.addSubview(shareButton)
```

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios. See Custom Interface.